# I am trying to create an SQL query to find the number of users singed up to both games

Tags: sql, select

[image: example table]

Here is the table in question, I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Your data is not normalised.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Why same `UserName` have different `GameUserID`?

Comment: I didn't make the table, I know it is a terrible design. I just have to create the query.

Comment: Can you please add a tag for the SQL dialect you're using? E.g. MySQL or SQL Server.

Comment: Take a look at GROUP BY, COUNT, and HAVING in your dialect's documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You can group by the user name, and then count many games a user is signed up to:

```
SELECT   username
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY username
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT gamename) = 2
```